# How to call CheckBoxPreference key to SettingsPreferences.java file

Tags: sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences, application-settings

I have created WebView app with MainActivity.java file on some knowledge of android java. My question is I want to display Screen ON always on selection of ChackBoxPreference when my app opens by users. I have coded as given below:

setting_preferences.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="@string/screen_on_off"
        android:summary="@string/keep_screen_on_selection"
        android:key="@string/display_screen"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When user selects this box then screen should be display always in my MainActivity.java code or else default settings.

SettingsActivity.java:

```js
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting_preferences);
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
    if (preferenceManager.getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("display_screen", true)){
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    } 
    else {
    //nothing to do as default value by phone display time
    }
}
```

How should I call FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON to my MainActivity.java file.
When I'm launching my emulator/debug app and opening settings screen, getting dialog box with app closing like "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Hope, I get a better solutions for this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution by myself.

By using `SharedPreferences` where we want to activate the `key` that given in `.xml` file can be used in any `.java` file by `SharedPreferences` as per our requirement.